# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (map(str, result))

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, typeerror, iterable

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6eada5f638a8> in <cell line: 8>()
     15     result = oddNumbers(l, r)
     16 
---> 17     fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
     18     fptr.write('\n')
     19 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

```py
import os
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    for i in range(l,r):
        if(i%2!=0):
            return(i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    fptr = sys.stdout
    l = int(input().strip())

    r = int(input().strip())

    result = oddNumbers(l, r)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your function `oddNumbers()` returns a single int. Perhaps you meant `yield i`?

Comment: How about testing your ` oddNumbers` function? What does `print(oddNumbers(1,0))` print? Also, learn some python grammer. The parenthesis after `if` and `return` are not needed.

Comment: @treuss i dont about this could you possibly help me ---> 18     fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
     19     fptr.write('\n')
     20 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

frist off all, function oddNumbers need to return array of oddNumbers instead of a single i, so we initialize empty array x and append every odd number found in range of l to r to it:

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    x = []
    for i in range(l, r):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            x.append(i)
    return x
```

then in printing result you need to iterate the array and join each string with "\n", to do this you can use this:

```
print('\n'.join(str(res) for res in result))
```

the complete code you can use is as follows:
def oddNumbers(l, r):
x = []
for i in range(l, r):
if i % 2 != 0:
x.append(i)
return x

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = int(input().strip())
    r = int(input().strip())
    result = oddNumbers(l, r)
    print('\n-------------------\n')
    print('\n'.join(str(res) for res in result))
```

i also believe using print instead of fptr.write would make code more simple and add to its readablity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure, thank you alot. I'll read the help and edit the answer as you say.